# Get application context in an abstract class

Tags: android, class, abstract, android-context

I am developing an android application. My question is can I get the application context in an abstract class? it gives me null pointer exception for the context variable and I assume it is maybe because I am using it inside an abstract class.

NOTE: In my code I have an abstract class (the abstract class itself extends Activity) that I use for instantiating other classes - Activites. In abstract class i create an instance of an activity helper, a class that handles some common activity-related functionality in the app. The is my activity helper class:

```
public class ActivityHelper { 
protected Activity mActivity; 

public static ActivityHelper createInstance(Activity activity, Context context) { 
return UIUtils.isTablet(context) ? 
new ActivityHelperTablet(activity) : 
new ActivityHelper(activity); 
} 

protected ActivityHelper(Activity activity) { 
mActivity = activity; 
}  
     }
```

Where the function isTablet receives a context variable that I create in my abstract class

```
     public static boolean isTablet(Context context) {
      // Can use static final constants like HONEYCOMB, declared in later versions 
      // of the OS since they are inlined at compile time. 
     return isHoneycomb() ||    
    ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout    &        
    Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE);
    }
```

the important part of BaseActivity:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity { 

Context context = this.getApplicationContext(); 
final ActivityHelper mActivityHelper = ActivityHelper.createInstance(this, context);
    }
```

But it gives me a null pointer exception. So I thought that it's maybe because of the abstract class.
And this is the log:

```
06-12 15:59:56.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1206): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-12 15:59:56.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at   
android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:101)
06-12 15:59:56.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at   
com.navayo.sec.voip.activities.BaseActivity.<init>(BaseActivity.java:35)
06-12 15:59:56.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at 
com.navayo.sec.voip.activities.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:43)
06-12 15:59:56.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at 
java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
06-12 15:59:56.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at   
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
06-12 15:59:56.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at 
android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
06-12 15:59:56.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at   
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1870)
```

Comment: The use of an abstract class mandates there will be a concrete implementation; not sure how the abstractness matters.

Comment: None of these things are related.  There's something wrong in your implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having an abstact class doesn't matter.

You have a null pointer because your context is null, which means somewhere in your methods there is an error, without the code to review i can't help you more.

EDIT:

```
public static ActivityHelper createInstance(Activity activity) { 
return UIUtils.isTablet(activity.getApplicationContext()); 
}
```

this should be enough. tell me if this is helping. simply an activity extends from context so you even might do: `UIUtils.isTablet(activity);`

now another subject would be the way you are actually creating the instances which is impossible to tell from your code, Activities are started with intents and have a lifecycle, they cannot be constructed with constructors.

EDIT 2:

Your issue is in this code:

```
final ActivityHelper mActivityHelper = ActivityHelper.createInstance(this, context);
```

At this time the activity is not yet created so your context ("this") is null.

you need to move the activity helper initialization in onCreate. the activity works a bit differently from other classes, it might be a good idea to also read a bit more on the activity lifecycle and see some more examples (try google :)).

the correct case would be:

```
private ActivityHelper mActivityHelper;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super(savedInstanceState);
// here do the initialization

mActivityHelper = ActivityHelper.createInstance(this);
.
.
.


}
```

Comment: ok, i will try it out. I know that maybe my question did not make sense, but I am stuck for several hours now, so I had to ask.

Comment: Does it have something to do with the fact that my main activity extends my abstract class BaseActivity and when I try to get the application context, maybe my activity is not even created.. But the problem is that I have to do the check if the device is a tablet or a phone first and foremost. (which i do in my base class)

Comment: As i said in my post and stated in the others that answered this question: it doesn't matter. That is not connected to the issue you are facing. how does your activity look like? can you post that code, including the UI Utils function and the base activity?

Comment: Ok, I've edited my post and added more code. See if something seems wrong to you. Thx

Comment: I've added onCreate method in my abstract class (because it extends Activity) and put my initialization of the context (context = getApplication()) there, so now it works. But is this legal? To have an onCreate method inside an abstract class?

Comment: Yes of course. you really need to read more on the whole concept and idea of the abstract class. in simple terms its just a way to group common functionalities of objects or provide a template for classes that will extend it. Its the foundation of object oriented programming opposed to writing procedural code. it simply means that you must extend it to use it.

Comment: Ok. This error confused me a bit I think. Thank u for your responses!